# Powershell: Changing the date modified on every folder/file within a profile older than 90 days

Tags: powershell, date, directory

I work for a school and we are trying to delete profiles older than 90 days. This has worked for the most part, but there are some profiles that have files within it that have been modified within 90 days. I've been trying to create a powershell script that changes the date modified on everything within the user folder to match the date modified on the user folder itself. I also want it to report what folders it changes as well as the dates of the folders that are changed. Here is what I have so far:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$Report = $Null
$Path = "C:\Users"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$UserFolders = $Path | GCI -Directory

ForEach ($UserFolder in $UserFolders){
    $UserName = $UserFolder.Name
    Get-ChildItem $Path -Force | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | ForEach-Object {
    $Dat = Get-Item "$Path\$UserName\NTUSer.dat" -force
    $DatTime = $Dat.LastWriteTime
    $AppData = Get-Item "$Path\$UserName\AppData"
    $AppDataFiles = Get-ChildItem $AppData -recurse | ? { !$_.psicontainer }
    $Down = Get-Item "$Path\$UserName\Downloads"
    $DownFiles = Get-ChildItem $Down -recurse | ? { !$_.psicontainer }
    $Desk = Get-Item "$Path\$UserName\Desktop"
    $DeskFiles = Get-ChildItem $Desk -recurse | ? { !$_.psicontainer }
    $Doc = Get-Item "$Path\$UserName\Documents"
    $DocFiles = Get-ChildItem $Doc -recurse | ? { !$_.psicontainer }
    If ($UserFolder.Name -ne "default"){
        $Dat.LastWriteTime = $UserFolder.LastWriteTime
            $AppData.LastWriteTime = $UserFolder.LastWriteTime
        foreach ($i in $AppDataFiles){
        $i.LastWriteTime = $AppData.LastWriteTime
        }
        $Down.LastWriteTime = $UserFolder.LastWriteTime
        foreach ($i in $DownFiles){
        $i.LastWriteTime = $Down.LastWriteTime
        }
        $Desk.LastWriteTime = $UserFolder.LastWriteTime
        foreach ($i in $DeskFiles){
        $i.LastWriteTime = $Desk.LastWriteTime
        }
        $Doc.LastWriteTime = $UserFolder.LastWriteTime
        foreach ($i in $DocFiles){
        $i.LastWriteTime = $Doc.LastWriteTime
        }
    }
    }
    Write-Host $UserName $DatTime
    Write-Host (Get-item $Path\$UserName -Force).LastWriteTime
    $Report = $Report + "$UserName`t$DatTime`r`n"
    $Dat = $Null
}
```

I know I currently have it set up to change the date modified for NTUser.dat, AppData, Downloads, Desktop, and Documents. I had to do it that way since those seemed to be the biggest issues. Although, I'd prefer it just change the date modified of everything with the parent folder. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work correctly. It just changes the date modified of every profile right now and not the ones that are older than 90 days. If someone could help me, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: For a start, you might want to read the docs about the `-Recurse` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`, because it might ease some things up.

Comment: Besides that, just a suggestion, would it not be more useful/easier to check the last login date of an account?